# Sum of Factorial Fraction

Tags: c

I'm working on a factorial sum which goes like: `1/1!+1/2!+1/3!...` until the desired count. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 1/(n * factorial(n-1));
}
int main ()
{
    int i, n;
    float sum=0;
    printf("Enter desired factorial fraction: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) sum = sum + factorial(i);
    printf("The value is %f\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

I have a small idea of what I'm doing, I am really new at this. My thought process was to set up the number crunching function (My jargon is probably off) and then initiate the main function. I thought I had the right set up, but after a couple hours with this I feel just lost. Any help and guidance will be much appreciated.

## Update

Here is the updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
float factorial(int n)
{
if (n==1)
return 1;
else
return ((1.0/n) * factorial(n-1.0));
}
int main ()
{
float i, n;
float sum=0;
printf("Enter desired factorial fraction: ");
scanf("%f", &n);
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) sum = sum + factorial(i);
printf("The value is %f\n", sum);
return 0;
}
```

So thank you guys, now the only thing left is for me to figure out why my input of "0" does not produce the result "1" since 0!=1. Should I move that if statement inside the "int main()"?

Comment: I think you got it wrong.... run it with small number and debug and see...

Comment: One slight comment. The factorial of a large number will result in overflow errors. Its better to find 1.0/factorial(n) drectly by using a `for` loop. Something like `d = 1; for(i = 1; i<=n; i++) d /= i;`. For large `n`, this should approach 0. Remember to put in checks for `n==0` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `factorial()` must be like this

```
int factorial(double n)
{
    if (n==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return ((1/n) * factorial(n-1));
}
```

Comment: The return value should be `float` instead of `int`.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Correct! +1 to you. Made the changes from int to double

Comment: you miss an open bracket in return (:

Answer (score 1):

You should use `float` as the return value of `factorial()` (you can only get `0` or `1` if you use `int`) and its logic is not correct.

You need to change it to

```
float factorial(int n)
{
    if (n==0)  // or n==1
        return 1;
    else
        return (1.0/n) * factorial(n-1);
}
```

Full code example can be seen here: http://ideone.com/o2XGhE

Comment: 1/n wont work since you have to add the factorial number not just the number

Comment: @Karthik The adding step is by `sum = sum + factorial(i);`, not in this function.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `factorial()` should be

```
int factorial(int n)
{
if
(n==0) return 1;
else
return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

And in your `main()` function, you should do something like:

```
for (i=1; i<=n; i++) sum = sum + 1.0 / factorial(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a separate function the calculate factorial(n)
than add the rest of the code, so the only recursive thing will be calculation of n!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this one :

```
int factorial(float n)
{
    if (n==1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (1/n) * factorial(n-1));
}
```

Comment: The return value should be `float` instead of `int`.

Comment: Thank you herohuyongtao, that small tip got my program to start running properly, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution is to use conditional ternary operator:

```
float factorial(float n) {
  return n ? ((1/n) * factorial(n-1)) : 1;  
}
```